# How to force positioning of a div to overlap with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4.5 to have a div positioned over two existing divs. Rather than trying to describe it with text, this picture illustrates what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

The navy and pink are two columns, and the white is outside of both of them.

My attempts to recreate something similar have not been succusfull. My current attempt is thus:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row pb-3" style="height: 520px;">
        <div class="p-3" style="float:left; background:red; height:220px; width:200px; z-index: 2;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="background:blue;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-9" style="background:pink;">&nbsp;</div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously this approach is not working. I'm not sure why it is not. What is the right approach to implement something like in the picture?

Comment: Do you want the content of the covered divs to flow around the white div or does not not matter?

Comment: Make the parent of the blue/pink containers, **row pb-3** `position: relative` and **p-3**  `position: absolute` and you can position **p-3** anywhere inside **row pb-3** (loose the `float`)...

Comment: @seesharper honestly I am not sure. The white div should never push far enough into the pink div that text in the pink div should be an issue, but if it were I would say float around it

Comment: @RenevanderLende do you mean put my row div inside a new div that is styled with `position: relative` ?

Comment: Inline CSS in HTML. That's not preferred at all `unless` necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row pb-3" style="height: 520px; position: relative">
        <div class="p-3" style="position:absolute; top: 100px; background:red; height:200px; width:200px; z-index: 2;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="background:blue;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-9" style="background:pink;">&nbsp;</div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the absolutely positioned div will cover the content in the others. Generally speaking by the way, `float` is nasty and to be avoided now that we have flex and grid and so on. It may be necessary if you need the content to flow around something, but usually it can and should be avoided.

Comment: Ah, I replied to your comment before I saw your answer. Thank you very much, works perfectly and clear explanation while I continue to learn this stuff.

Comment: Inline CSS in HTML. That's not preferred at all `unless` necessary.

Comment: Of course @AlwaysHelping, but I am just following the OP's code to show how to do it. But yes, of course you want to put the styling into classes.